# Mysql Complex query for generate all table with count zero if no records found

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've a complex query. And I'm freeze on position :(. 
Here is my tables.
users:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `office_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `district_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `upazilla_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `del_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `service` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `recipient_number` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `office_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `del_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `creation_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `service_list` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `service_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `del_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `service_transaction` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `service_transaction_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `service_id` int(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

here, service-id = service_transaction.service_transaction_id .

I worte a query:

```
select users.id, users.office_name,service_transaction.service_id , COUNT(service_transaction.service_id) as service_total
from users
LEFT JOIN service on users.id = service.office_id
LEFT JOIN service_transaction on service_transaction.service_transaction_id = service.id
WHERE( users.del_status = 0 and users.type='agency')
GROUP BY users.office_name , users.id, service_transaction.service_id
```

It return:

```
id   office_name  Service_id  service_total
=============================================
2    Ctg Office      2             2
2    Ctg Office      3             4
2    Ctg Office      4             3
7    Dhaka Office   NULL           0
```

But My Desire output is:

```
id   office_name  Service_id  service_total
=============================================
2    Ctg Office      2             2
2    Ctg Office      3             4
2    Ctg Office      4             3
2    Ctg Office      5             0
2    Ctg Office      6             0

7    Dhaka Offc      2             0
7    Dhaka Offc      3             0
7    Dhaka Offc      4             0
7    Dhaka Offc      5             0
7    Dhaka Offc      6             0
```

It means, i've to show all services under each office, if no service, count should be zero.

Comment: So your table `users` contains offices. A user is an office in your model. You should better have called the table `offices`, though, in my opinion. And the table `service` contains the services defined for offices, i.e. office=2|service=2, office=2|service=3 etc. You want to show a row for office=2|service=6, too. Does such a record exist in `services`, i.e. is a service 6 even defined for office 2?

Comment: Anyway, you should group by `service.id`, not by `service_transaction.service_id`. Maybe this already solves your problem.

Comment: Plz show some dummy data from table or create fiddle

Answer (score 1):

```
select temp.id office_id , temp.office_name, temp.svcic ,count(service_transaction.service_id) as service_total, count(recipient.id) as total_count from (select users.id, users.office_name ,service_list.id svcic from users,service_list WHERE users.del_status = 0 and users.type='agency' )  temp LEFT JOIN service on temp.id = service.office_id and service.del_status=0 LEFT JOIN service_transaction on service_transaction.service_id = temp.svcic and service_transaction.service_transaction_id=service.id right outer JOIN recipient on recipient.office_id = temp.id group by temp.id , temp.office_name, temp.svcic ORDER BY temp.id,temp.office_name
```

please try the above code.
for more readable, you should maintain intend

Answer (score 0):

```
select users.id, users.office_name,service_transaction.service_id , COUNT(service_transaction.service_id) as service_total
from users
JOIN service 
LEFT JOIN service_transaction on service_transaction.service_transaction_id = service.id
WHERE( users.del_status = 0 and users.type='agency')
GROUP BY users.office_name , users.id, service_transaction.service_id
```

Try above query.

Comment: Hi Sagar, this is not working. I also wrote same query before . Example: for "Office Dhaka" showing same service total same as "Ctg office". But "Dhaka office" have no data, So, Dhaka office should be 0 for all service count

Answer (score 0):

Try this if not solve then let me know you data in table service and service_transaction table.

SELECT users.id, users.office_name,service_transaction.service_id , SUM(IF(service.id IS  NULL, 0, 1)) as service_total

from users

JOIN service on users.id = service.office_id

JOIN service_transaction on service_transaction.service_transaction_id = service.id

WHERE( users.del_status = 0 and users.type='agency')

GROUP BY users.office_name , users.id, service_transaction.service_id

Comment: Hi @Jack,  My goal is to show all office. Though many office's might not any entry on service table. That case they've output like this:     Dhaka office  [service_name]->1  [service-count]->0